# jquery ColorPicker not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I Have The Following code to show ColorPicker when click button

The issue

```
<div class="main_container">
  <button type="button" class="change_color">change color</button>
  <div  style="display:none;"  class="change_container">
    <div class="BackgroundPopup_colorView__U3of1">
    <div class="picker_launcher" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 24px; height: 24px; border: 1px solid rgb(208, 213, 221); box-shadow: rgba(16, 24, 40, 0.1) 0px 4px 8px -2px, rgba(16, 24, 40, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px -2px; border-radius: 4px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


                
$('.change_color').on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest(".main_container").children(".change_container").show();
    var picker_btn=$(this).closest(".main_container").children(".picker_launcher");

    let picker = new ColorPicker(picker_btn, "#4c0082");
});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest(".main_container").children(".picker_launcher")` does not work. use `$(this).closest(".main_container").find(".picker_launcher")` Because `picker_launcher` is not a direct child of `main_container`

Comment: also $(this).closest(".main_container").find(".picker_launcher") not work

Comment: `$(this).closest(".main_container").find(".picker_launcher")` should return the element. When I run this code inside the click event, it returns the element. `$(this).closest(".main_container").children(".picker_launcher")`

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you gave us the reference to the colorpicker plugin you are refering 2, maybe it's nothing else that is wrong.

Comment: it return the element ok , but issue in let picker = new ColorPicker(picker_btn, "#4c0082");

Comment: I use this code https://codepen.io/TEK-Projects/pen/NWRRgRv

Comment: I've extracted the relevant css/js from that pen into a fiddle with your code.  That colr_pickr won't work in SO as it doesn't handle localStorage unavailable (not sure why it needs localStorage, didn't look).   In the fiddle, it gives `setAttribute` is not a function: https://jsfiddle.net/9sot83a4/  **always check the console for errors** (and include them in the question)   `is not a function` generally means you've passed the wrong type.

Comment: Your issue is that colr_pckr is a vanilla-javascript component and, as such, doesn't understand the jquery collection that you're passing with `new ColorPicker(picker_btn, ...` - you need to pass a DOM element, ie `new ColorPicker(picker_btn[0], ...`  updated, working, fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9sot83a4/1/

Comment: freedomn-m very thanks it works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @r-tek/colr_pickr
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@r-tek/colr_pickr
> Colr Pickr is a vanilla JavaScript color picking component

The provided (in comments) codepen also does not use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

The color_pickr component is vanilla-javascript only and, as such, doesn't understand/recognise jquery objects/collections.

This code (with children() fixed to find())

```
var picker_btn=$(this).closest(".main_container").find(".picker_launcher");
let picker = new ColorPicker(picker_btn, "#4c0082");
```

passes a jquery object to ColorPicker which responds with an error

```
t.setAttribute is not a function
```

*(`t` because code is min'd)*

Instead, your code needs to pass a DOM object.   As long as you are sure `picker_btn` selects an element, you can use:

```
var picker_btn=$(this).closest(".main_container").find(".picker_launcher");
let picker = new ColorPicker(picker_btn[0], "#4c0082");
```